# Testing long session timeouts

Tags: .net, testing

So I need to know whether the session on the application I developed expires in 60 days. I know it isn't realistic to really test for 60 days; in these types of cases, what do you usually do at work to test long session timeouts?

Do you select an acceptable amount of time (like an hour) to consider this as working? How do you select what amount of time? Or some other method?